# Minimum deviation position in prism

Tags: optics, optical-materials

Why does deviation become minimum at minimum deviation position? What is its importance in practical applications?

Answer (score 0):

(a) In general the angle of emergence of a light ray through a prism is different from its angle of incidence, *i*. But since light paths are reversible, this implies that two angles of incidence correspond to each angle of deviation, *D* – except in the case where the beam goes symmetrically through the prism. So a graph of *D* against *i* must have a maximum or a minimum in this symmetrical case. It's easy to show that it's a minimum.

(b) The significance of $D_{min}$ is that the graph of *D* against *i* is almost flat around the minimum. We'll get almost the same deviation from the prism for a small range of angles *i* at which we shine the light, even if not *exactly* at $i_{sym}$.

Comment: *It's easy to show that it's a minimum.* How? This seems to be the point of the first question, but you are not answering it. Part (b) is good, though.

Comment: A couple of numerical calculations, one of which is for the symmetrical case, will suffice!